# Assigning values to object fields in Java?

Tags: java

For example, if I have this:

```
class Test{
  private int id;

  public Test(int id){
    id=id;
  }
}
```

In this case, how can I assign the value of the `id` parameter to the `id` field?

Comment: `this.id=id` `this` means the current instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 this.id = id;
```

because `this` refers to the current object.

Learn more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: ...because the method parameter `id` shadows the instance field `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this`:

```
public Test(int id){
    this.id = id;
}
```

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use assign:

```
this.id = id;
```

Answer (score 0):

data instance hiding is happening here.your local variable is hiding your instance variable.
so to access the instance data , always use " this"

so this.name=name